# Using toString() changes the value of my date?

Tags: c#

I'm using parsing a JSON Object, and it's parsing properly using Newtonsoft.

> "signed_date_time":"2016-08-13T22:05:22Z"

Basically when I do

```
jsonObject["signed_date_time"].ToString();
```

it returns

> 8/13/2016 10:05:22 PM

How do I fix this? I want it to to return

> 2016-08-13T22:05:22Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a [DateParseHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm) property and set it to `DateParseHandling.None`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't come up when I tried to use it, but this worked, "Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None"